# Redirect all example.com/paths that don't start with example.com/wiki to example.com/wiki - NginX Proxy

Tags: proxy, nginx, reverse-proxy, rewrite

I recently moved my site from Wordpress to confluence, and I'm having trouble with page redirects. Ive setup a custom 404 page for my Confluence, but it only works if you type

https://www.freesoftwareservers.com/asdasdas

But if you go to an old link, like

https://www.freesoftwareservers.com/index.php/2015/09/03/install-dd-wrt-on-linksys-ea6500/

It takes you to my "confluence" page, but the `/wiki` is a special plugin that I want to be the public facing side. I access the page via a different subdomain then www.

My "workaround" would be one of two things,

1) Redirect all `https://www.freesoftwareservers.com/index.php/*` to `https://www.freesoftwareservers.com/wiki`

2) Redirect all `https://www.freesoftwareservers.com/(Anything BUT /wiki)` to `https://www.freesoftwareservers.com/wiki`

I found something close on NginX site, but it was more complicated that what I need and I was having trouble with the expression needed.

https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/

Here’s a sample NGINX rewrite rule that uses the rewrite directive. It matches URLs that begin with the string /download and then include the /media/ or /audio/ directory somewhere later in the path. It replaces those elements with /mp3/ and adds the appropriate file extension, .mp3 or .ra. The $1 and $2 variables capture the path elements that aren’t changing. As an example, /download/cdn-west/media/file1 becomes /download/cdn-west/mp3/file1.mp3.

```
server {
    ...
    rewrite ^(/download/.*)/media/(.*)\..*$ $1/mp3/$2.mp3 last;
    rewrite ^(/download/.*)/audio/(.*)\..*$ $1/mp3/$2.ra  last;
    return  403;
    ...
}
```

Perhaps I need to split this into 2 parts, a server block that returns 404 and a 404 handler, but I'd like to keep this all in my existing nginx server block.

BTW I am already using the following rewrite rule to redirect domain.com/ to domain.com/wiki, but that only works if you type https://www.freesoftwareservers.com without anything at the end.

```
rewrite     ^/$ /wiki permanent;
```

Any help is appreciated, there are many broken links to my site floating around the interweb :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well as soon as I posted a Bounty, I figured it out while I was writing a better description for my question...

```
rewrite ^/index.php /wiki permanent;
```